# Do Trenitalia operate trains from Pré Saint Didier to Ivrea?

Tags: trains, italy, trenitalia

My search results on Trenitalia's site shows "No Travel Solution Found" in looking for trains from Pré Saint Didier to Ivrea. I know there is a line and an end station there and it runs to Aosta.

Has something changed, or is this line operated by a different company, and if so how do I find schedules?

Answer (score 10):

On to the wiki page of [Stazione di Pré-Saint-Didier](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stazione_di_Pr%C3%A9-Saint-Didier) is stated (under "Movimento")

> La stazione era in ultimo servita da treni regionali di Trenitalia
>   fino al 24 dicembre 2015, giorno in cui la linea è stata sospesa al
>   traffico per decisione della Regione Valle d'Aosta e sostituito da
>   autocorse.

Google translates this as

> The station was finally served by regional trains Trenitalia until December 24, 2015, the day when the line was suspended traffic for decision of the Valle d'Aosta region and replaced by bus rides.

I'm afraid you'll have to take the bus.

Comment: FYI, *autocorse* = bus rides.

Comment: That is very good information to know. Would skiing travelers be able to return from La Thuile to Pré Saint Didier and board a bus to Aosta directly? Where is the bus terminal in Pré Saint Didier? Does SAVDA's  route take you back to Courmayeur to catch a connecting bus to Aosta or can one continue down the valley to Aosta?